# D3 v4 Update-Pattern for Groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given the following layout:

```
<g>
   ... // many nodes
   <g>
      <circle></circle>
      <text></text>
   </g>
   ...
</g>
```

How would a correct update pattern look like in d3 v4?
What do I have to use as parameter in merge(?), how often do I have to call merge (only on node? node + circle + text ?)

I created an working example on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvvfsg97/6/

Code:

```
function update(items) {
  node = nodeLayer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(items, function(d) { return d.id; })

  node = node.enter() // insert
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("circle") // insert
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .merge(nodeLayer.selectAll('.node > circle')) // is this correct?! // merge
    .attr('fill', 'red') // just for testing purposes
    .exit().remove(); // exit

  node.append("text") // insert
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .merge(nodeLayer.selectAll('.node > text')) // is this correct?! // merge
      .attr('fill', 'green')  // just for testing purposes
      .exit().remove();

    node.merge(nodeLayer.selectAll('.node')) // is this correct?!  // merge 
    .attr('class', 'anotherClass')
    .exit().remove(); // does not work // exit
}
```

Could someone bring some clarity in terms of how to use enter(), merge(), exit() in groups?

I potentially like to do changes in every stage for every element.

---

**Update**: I simplified the example, I don't need links or a force-layout. My question is only about the update-pattern, not about forces. The updated jsfiddle does not have the force-layout.

Comment: have you seen https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218? it's been updated with merge

Comment: @Frame91, I'm glad you realised that you have 2 different questions here: One regarding the update pattern itself and other regarding how to update an force. They are substantially different questions. The problem right now is that any answer which addresses your general question (the update pattern) will fail to correctly address the force problem, as the two answers you have now. Thus, I suggest that you delete this question and post another one, regarding how to create an update pattern for groups containing texts and circles (and that will be easily answered).

Comment: I am not interested in the force-layout. I only care about the update pattern. I just used an existing example on jsfiddle which happens to have a force layout. sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: I also cannot delete this question as it has answers. However, nowhere did I ask about force-layouts, so I hope I still get a suitable answer in this thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are over complicating the pattern.  Here's your update function written properly:

```
function update(items) {

  var node = nodeLayer.selectAll(".node") // bind the data, this is update
    .data(items, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  node.exit().remove(); // exit, remove the g

  nodeEnter = node.enter() // enter, append the g
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  nodeEnter.append("circle") // enter, append the circle on the g
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('fill', 'red');

  nodeEnter.append("text") // enter, append the text on the g
    .attr("dy", 3)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr('fill', 'green');

  node = nodeEnter.merge(node); // enter + update on the g

  node.attr('transform', function(d){ // enter + update, position the g
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });

  node.select("text") // enter + update on subselection
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

}
```

Here it is running with multiple calls:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  
    var nodeLayer = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',500)
      .attr('height',500);
      
    update([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'A',
        x: Math.random() * 500,
        y: Math.random() * 500
      },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'B',
        x: Math.random() * 500,
        y: Math.random() * 500
      },{
        id: 3,
        name: 'C',
        x: Math.random() * 500,
        y: Math.random() * 500
      }
    ]);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        update([
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'A',
          x: Math.random() * 500,
          y: Math.random() * 500
        },{
          id: 4,
          name: 'This is a new name...',
          x: Math.random() * 500,
          y: Math.random() * 500
        },{
          id: 3,
          name: 'C',
          x: Math.random() * 500,
          y: Math.random() * 500
        }
      ]);
    }, 3000);
  
    function update(items) {
      
      var node = nodeLayer.selectAll(".node")
        .data(items, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });
        
      node.exit().remove(); // exit, remove the g

      nodeEnter = node.enter() // enter the g
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");
        
      nodeEnter.append("circle") // enter the circle on the g
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .attr('class', 'circle')
        .attr('fill', 'red');

      nodeEnter.append("text") // enter the text on the g
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .attr('fill', 'green');
        
      node = nodeEnter.merge(node); // enter + update
          
      node.attr('transform', function(d){
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
      });
      
      node.select("text")
       .text(function(d) {
         return d.name;
       });

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. However, the main problem remains open. How do I update circle/text within the group? Even though you provided a working example for that specific case, I do need to update circle/text. My example might be misleading as it is indeed not necessary to merge circle/text in there.. Could you add circle/text update to your example?

Comment: @Frame91, opps, missed that use case, see updated code snippets above.  You just select the text as a subselection of the enter+update.

Comment: Brilliant answer - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I've done this recently in my code - I use select(subSelector) on the current selection that contains the  elements. In your example I would change it as follows:

```
function update(items) {
var node = nodeLayer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(items, function(d) { return d.id; })

var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .merge(node.select('circle'))
    .attr('fill', 'red');

nodeEnter.append("text") // insert
    .attr("dy", 3)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .merge(node.select('text'))
    .attr('fill', 'green');

// You only need to call remove on the group, all the other exit().remove() calls are superfluous
node.exit().remove();

simulation
    .nodes(items);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  nodeLayer = svg.append('g'),
  node;

var list = [];
var links = [];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(list)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(200))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .on("tick", ticked);

function createNodes(index) {
  links.push({
    'source': 0,
    'target': index
  })
  list.push({
    "id": index,
    "name": "server " + index
  });
  return list;
}

var iteration = 0;
update(createNodes(iteration)); // just simulating updates 

d3.interval(function(timer) {
  iteration++;
  update(createNodes(iteration));
}, 1000); //<-- this was commented out incorrectly just now

function update(items) {
  var dataJoin = nodeLayer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(items, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
  node = dataJoin.enter() // insert
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("circle") // insert
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .merge(dataJoin) // not the class, the actual selected group you called enter() on
    .select('.circle')
    .style('fill', 'red') // just for testing purposes
    .exit().remove(); // exit

  node.append("text") // insert
    .attr("dy", 3)
    .attr('class', 'text')
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .merge(dataJoin)
    .select('.text')
    .style('fill', 'green') // fill is a style

  dataJoin.exit().remove();
  simulation.nodes(list);
  simulation.force("link").links(links);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}

function ticked() {
  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var a = d.x || 0;
    var b = d.y || 0;
    return "translate(" + a + ", " + b + ")";
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="300" width="300"></svg>
```

there are bunch of bugs,

first of all 'update'(misnomer) should be called with the list of all the data nodes not just the change.

you might want to explore https://bl.ocks.org/ and copy how people are doing force directed graphs. you need links to have forces.

the idea behind merge is to compare the new list with the old list, which means you need to use dataJoin or the group that has the data/id attached.

I am not an expert, do take a look at all the examples of force-directed graphs and see how they update/merge. (there's more than 1 way to update/restart the graph)

Comment: surprised at the negative voting, considering i provided fixed and working code that demonstrates the syntax of merge. not inclined to update, also suggest you remake this question, thanks

Comment: also, your example does not work. See https://jsfiddle.net/cvvfsg97/7/ where I used your example for 'text' but Johns approach for 'circle'

Comment: you can't just copy a small piece of the code and expect it to work, update is supposed to receive all the nodes not just a single node, merge() returns the common pieces, so if you change the list to another set of nodes [a] with [b] then merge returns empty set. try running my code in its entirety

Comment: Sorry I think my example confuses you. I'm fully aware that update takes the full list. In my example, this is just ONE node as array, to simplify the example.

Comment: for some reason the code that adds nodes gets commented out haha, you need to see nodes added to understand the merge. copy the edited code

Comment: sorry - my bad, copy/paste failed