# D3.js (V4) Modifying Force Directed Graph with groups as nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have successfully created a force layout graph with D3 V4, and am now trying to add functionality where when you click a node, it is removed from from the graph without having to redraw the graph each time. I am trying to follow the [new general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), which I can get to work when my nodes are just circles, but in my graph the nodes are groups which include a circle and two labels. When I try to group my nodes and apply the general update pattern, I am getting [strange behavior (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/3wLvk2xb/).

I am very new to D3 and I think I am misunderstanding something about enter and exit statements, or the order in which things should be done. If any of you could take a look at my build graph function and let me know whats up, that would be great.

**Code** (forgive formatting, needed for JSFiddle)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GraphViz</title>
</head>

<body name="top" class="container">
    <div class="graphPanel" style="height: 800px">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
    </div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        data = {
  "nodes": [
    {
        "type": "User ID",
        "detail": "Bob Smith",
        "data": "7d7c...1e1c",
        "id": "0"
    },
    {
        "type": "Device",
        "detail": "MacOS",
        "data": "6334...1e1c",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "type": "Device",
        "detail": "Windows",
        "data": "185c...1e1c",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "type": "Device",
        "detail": "Windows",
        "data": "6334...1e1c",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "type": "Device",
        "detail": "Android",
        "data": "6334...1e1c",
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "type": "Device",
        "detail": "iOS Browser",
        "data": "2312...1e1c",
        "id": "5"
    },
    {
        "type": "Shipping Address",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "San Jose, CA 95113",
        "id": "6"
    },
    {
        "type": "Account Name",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "4d6f....aa10",
        "id": "7"
    },
    {
        "type": "Account Login",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "bsmith",
        "id": "8"
    },
    {
        "type": "Credit Card Hash",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "1cca...81e1",
        "id": "9"
    },
    {
        "type": "SSN",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "4fed...3er5",
        "id": "10"
    },
    {
        "type": "Account Number",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "78945648",
        "id": "11"
    },
    {
        "type": "Email",
        "detail": "",
        "data": "bob@bobsmith.com",
        "id": "12"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "1",
        "id": "0"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "2",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "3",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "4",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "5",
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "6",
        "id": "5"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "7",
        "id": "6"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "8",
        "id": "7"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "9",
        "id": "8"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "10",
        "id": "9"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "11",
        "id": "10"
    },
    {
        "source": "0",
        "target": "12",
        "id": "11"
    }
  ]
}

    buildGraph(data.links, data.nodes);

  function buildGraph(links, nodes) {
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = $("svg").width(),
    height = $("svg").height(),
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(200))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .alphaTarget(1)
    .on("tick", ticked);

    var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"),
    link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
    node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

    var circle, label, data;

    restart();

    function restart() {

      node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});
      node.exit().remove();
      node = node.enter().append("g")
      .merge(node);

      circle = node.append("circle")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); }).attr("r", 8)
      .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;})
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

      link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
      link.exit().remove();
      link = link.enter().append("line")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.source + "-" + d.target;
      })
      .merge(link);

      label = node.append("text")
      .attr("font-size", "15")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("class", "nodeLabel")
      .html(function(d) { 
        var detail = d.detail === "" ? "" : ": " + d.detail;
        return d.type + detail;
      });

      data = node.append("text")
      .html(function(d) { 
        return d.data;
      })
      .attr("class", "nodeLabel");

      simulation.nodes(nodes);
      simulation.force("link").links(links);
      simulation.alpha(1).restart();
    }

    $("circle").click(function() {
      console.log(links)
      $("circle").removeClass("selected");
      d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      nodes.forEach(function(thisNode) {
        if (thisNode.id === id) {
          var index = nodes.indexOf(thisNode);
          nodes.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      for(var i = links.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        if(links[i].target.id === id || links[i].source.id === id) {
          links.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      restart();
    });

    function ticked() {
      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      circle
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

      label
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.typeCode === "did" ? d.x + 35 : d.x + 25; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

      data
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.typeCode === "did" ? d.x + 35 : d.x + 25; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 15; });
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }
  }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im changing my  previous answer since it was completly wrong, look at this link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625978/d3-v4-update-pattern-for-groups)
, that should keep you going just fine. and I still maintain my commennt about you binding your delete event to the circles, you have to do bind it to your nodes ()

Comment: In fact I have foun that you have not only this problem, other error is that you attached the delete to the circle itself so, **the new circles** you add **dont have the ability to delete nodes** from the graph. Im working on your fiddle to fix it